# See health of a living entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to get this information?
I hit my Iron Golem by accident and then found out, that they do not regain health.

PS: I know that mods could do that, but I don't want to use mods for this. If it is not possible in vanilla-survival, I just rather accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**TL:DR - No, not really.**

Full Answer:

By using command blocks and scoreboard counters, you can track the health of a specific mob on the scoreboard. However, since you already specified that you want to do this is vanilla survival, this would not be possible for you. Additionally, you would have to name the mob, then set up a counter to specifically monitor the mob's HP, display it as a scoreboard counter, etc - all of which sounds like more work than you're wanting to do for one iron golem.